# Error en bundle install ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy trabajando en Windows 7, pero al intentar crear un nuevo proyecto el día de hoy me da problemas. Por lo que entiendo es con el certificado SSL. Si bien existe documentación sobre el error, no lo he logrado corregir.
Dejo el error que me retorna la consola:

```
create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install Fetching source index from rubygems.org/ Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4):
Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL
certificate for rubygems.org/. There is a chance you are
experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system
doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To
connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change
'https' to 'http'. Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4):
Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL
certificate for rubygems.org/. There is a chance you are
experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system
doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To
connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change
'https' to 'http'. Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4):
Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL
certificate for rubygems.org/. There is a chance you are
experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system
doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To
connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change
'https' to 'http'. Could not verify the SSL certificate for
rubygems.org/. There is a chance you are experiencing a
man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the
CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL
certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using
SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.

miguelangel@DESKTOP-RHJ8M9N /c/sites $ rails -v Rails 4.2.5.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer necesitas actualizar el certificado SSL en tu sistema. Prueba con `gem update --system`. Si el problema persiste, entonces podrías probar en tu `Gemfile` a cambiar:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

por:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, gem update no me funciono pero al quitar la "s" todo corre bien al parecer. Por ahora me basta para seguir aprendiendo...  Saludos.